# Is there a way to backup quick books pro 2008 in multi user mode?

Tags: quickbooks

We are wanting to backup our quick books files in multi user mode to an external hard drive, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In the evening when noone is using it.

Pretty much that is it, or? At least it was last time I checked. It is file based, keeps locks around, you are likely to not get a consistent database image. If you have nigher uptime / people requirements, you need to move up financially to a system using a database server or some sort.

Comment: Yep, that's what we do for one of our locations that still uses Quickbooks.  I have a simple script that copies the entire QB folder/files to another server at 2am daily when the file isn't in use.  That second server gets backed up nightly via the normal backup policies.  This ensures we have a local quick restore copy as well as something on the backup archives.

Comment: Not to mention that Quickbooks has its own, scheduleable backup function.